# Function to determine whether 2 numbers are =, > or <

Tags: c++, function

I have a question about a function to determinate if a number is `>`, `=` or `<`  than another.

If I have for example:

```
 int fun(int a, int b)
 {
    if (a > b)
        return a;
    else
        if (b > a)
            return b;
        else
            return 0
 }
```

(I don't want to use any `cout` that interacts with the user).
Now if I give 2 numbers it gives me `a`, `b` or `0`. But for example if a put in the function `a = -1` and `b = 0`, the function clearly returns `0` even if the 2 numbers are not equal.

Yes, I could check before calling the function if the 2 numbers are the same. Or I could use a variable to see in which case I am, for example:

```
int fun(int a, int b)
{
    int k = 0;
    if (a > b)
        return k;
    else
        if (b > a)
            return k+1;
        else
            return k+2
}
```

But all these solutions are not so elegant. Is there a way to distinguish a `0` `int` from another? Or in any case is there a method to be sure that a return value come from a given point in this case?

Comment: So, you want it to return `max(a,b)`, unless `a == b`?

Comment: You could return a number that is not equal to either `a` or `b`

Comment: you can try to add a flag telling you that b or a = 0;

Comment: Return 1 if A is greater, return -1 if B is greater, return 0 if they are equal.

Comment: If you want to determine the "greatest value" between two numbers then your function works well whether any of the number is 0 or not.
If you want to determine which "number is bigger" from two then you can return 1 for A, -1 for B and 0 for `A==B`

Comment: IMHO, a function like this wastes more time in the setup to call and the return overhead than the contents provide.  In other words, this should be pasted inline in the code and not as a free standing function.

Comment: Just return `a - b` and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `else` when the statement inside the `if` returns. I would additionally return something with actual meaning, rather than just an int. For example:

`enum Relationship { LessThan = -1, Equal, GreaterThan};`

```
    if(a==b)
        return Relationship::Equal;
    if(a>b)
        return Relationship::GreaterThan;
    return Relationship::LessThan;
```

In general, I probably wouldn't bother writing a fucntion like this because managing this trinary output seems more effort than it's worth, but I'm assuming this is some kind of exercise.

Comment: `Relationship::Equal` is the C++ syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pointers

```
 int* fun(int *a, int *b)
 {
    if (*a > *b)
        return a;
    else
        if (*b > *a)
            return b;
        else
            return NULL
 }
```

if return value isn't NULL you can give maximum number from returned value